# Save and restore webextensions options page

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am new to programming and i am building a simple add-on for firefox but i am using web extensions, my options page has a few check box's

I need to save the values of these checkbox's and then restore them, Sample code is appreciated.

```js
function saveOptions(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  browser.storage.local.set({
    box1: document.querySelector("#box1").checked
  });
}

function restoreOptions() {

 var getting = browser.storage.local.get("box1");

  function setCurrentChoice(result) {
    document.querySelector("#box1").checked = result.box1 || false
  }

  function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
  }

  

  getting.then(setCurrentChoice, onError);

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreOptions);
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

```html
<form>
<p><label>Box1<input id="box1" type="checkbox" /></label></p>
<p><label>Box2<input id="box2" type="checkbox" /></label></p>
<p><label>Box3<input id="box3" type="checkbox" /></label></p>
<p><label>Box4<input id="box4" type="checkbox" /></label></p>
<p><label>Box5<input id="box5" type="checkbox" /></label></p>
<p><button type="submit">Save</button></p>
</form>
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

The code i got from Firefox's example works in saving value of one check box, but how do i save and restore all the values of different box ?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate [Completely lost on how to save Chrome extension popup window content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284528/completely-lost-on-how-to-save-chrome-extension-popup-window-content).

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to add your *manifest.json* .

Comment: @Makyen its not a duplicate, but i will look into that post maybe i will find something useful, and my manifest json , don't have anything specifically its only asking for storage as permission.

Comment: OK I'll double check it within 24 hrs.  I'm on someone else's computer right now.  At any rate, it seems to work in this add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/570430/file/settings/options.js#top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use.  My add-on also uses only checkboxes in options.  As in your example, the options are identified by element id, so including the HTML would be redundant.  I have no save button; changes are recorded in realtime whenever options are checked or unchecked.  It's largely copied from the online documentation for this feature.  Note that this variant uses jQuery, though.

```
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page

// if one of the checkboxes is clicked, store the new value of the
// corresponding parameter:
$("input").click(function () {
  var setting = {};
  setting[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).get(0).checked;
  chrome.storage.local.set(setting);
});

function restoreOptions() {
 // For each checkbox, see if stored value of setting has changed
 $("input").each(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   chrome.storage.local.get(id, function (setting) {
     if (Object.keys(setting).length) {
      $("#"+id).get(0).checked = setting[id] ? "checked" : undefined;
     }
     else {
      // This block runs only the first time the settings page is opened.
      init = {};
      init[id] = true;
      chrome.storage.local.set(init);
     }
   });
 });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreOptions);
```

It's possible that, as @Mayken suggests, your problem might be with manifest.json.  [The example in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page#Adding_settings) instructs one to put options.html in a directory called settings, and declares this in manifest.json by setting `options_ui.page` to `"options.html"`.  I found I had to spell it out as `"settings/options.html"` to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for this, i like your approach of saving in real time, but i get a error "SyntaxError: missing )" when i use your code

Comment: Hey @Lori Thanks for this, but i still get "SyntaxError: missing )" , and adding ) just keeps pops up a another error like a loop or something, I will keep trying to fix this but, would it be possible for you to test this code out once and see if there is something i am missing ?

Comment: Thanks mate, I finally got it to work, turns out it didn't work because jquery had to be included in the html as-well, Really appropriate the help.