# How to maintain the state of button in Chrome extension pop up once it is clicked.(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension which basically has a button. The button changes color and text on click and alternates between "Enable" and "Disable".
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2tovyz6/8/) for explanation and to see what I am talking about.

Now what I want is that once I click the button and it goes to disable condition, it should remain disabled until clicked again.How can I do it?

I know that whenever the extension popup is opened ,it is like a new page, so I would have to save the previous state using **chrome.storage** and load this state every time popup is clicked. I get a slight idea by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41289802/8113544) ans here. But I cannot wrap my head around it fully.

My manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Parental Control",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to change the background color of the current page.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background":{
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "run_at": "document_start"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        width:200px;
        height:300px;
        white-space: nowrap;
       background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(248, 246, 242, 0.8), rgba(248, 246, 242, 0.8)), url(back_main.jpg) repeat;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="css/button.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/logo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src="icon.png" alt="Control" class="center" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
      <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" id="buttonclick">
  <span>Enable Control</span></button>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var click = document.getElementById("buttonclick")

    click.addEventListener("click", handler);
});
var count = 1;
    function handler() {
        var property = document.getElementById('buttonclick');
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#4f8ff7"
            property.innerHTML = "<span>Enable control</span>"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#a84237"
            property.innerHTML = "<span>Disable control</span>"

            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly, you are using 'count' like a boolean to indicate if the button is enabled or not. You should be able to achieve saved state by calling:

```
var obj = {};
obj['buttonState'] = count;
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function() {
  // this called after the save
});
```

To retrieve, you simply do the reverse:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('buttonState', function(data) {   
    // this is called after the retrieve.
    count = data['buttonState'];
});
```

Comment: will this maintain the state per tab ID, or globally?

Comment: this would be globally because the extension is per window/profile instance. You could do it per tab as well though by modifying to the object to save buttonState along with the tabId so it would be per tab. But that is risky as it could lead to a large number of entries over time.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you need to use storage.local - you also need to allow for the value not being in storage yet, so the neatest way is to use the default value feature of the get function:

```
function handler() {
    chrome.storage.local.get({count: 0}, function (result) {
        var count = result.count;
        var property = document.getElementById('buttonclick');
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#4f8ff7"
            property.innerHTML = "<span>Enable control</span>"
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#a84237"
            property.innerHTML = "<span>Disable control</span>"
            count = 0;
        }
        chrome.storage.local.set({count: count});
    });
}
```

You could optimise by not bothering to set count and just using

```
chrome.storage.local.set({count: 1 - count});
```